# Determine which header is at top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with headers  in each section that contain data about the cells in that section. As the table scrolls I want the headers to have transparent backgrounds, until each section hits the top of the view (or even as it gets very close to the top) and sticks (stock header behavior for UITableViewStylePlain).

I can get a reference to the top header using headerViewForSection and tableView:visibleCells, but I'd like a solution that would allow the header to manage it's own position so that each headerView will determine when to transition to transparent.

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "manager its own position"?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to somehow use delegation to allow the headerView (which is a UView subclass) to receive notification of it's own position within the parent view as the parent view (the table view) is scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyValueObserving to add an observer(tableview header) to UITableView's `contentOffset` property, message will send to you headerView continuously when table view is scrolling.

If you don't need continuous notification, you can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` in you view controller, post custom notification in `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` or other method in `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Your headerView should register as receiver of
 the custom notification in advance.

**update:**

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` will also be called continuous when table view scrolls.

Comment: I don't necessarily need continuous notification, but I do need notification as one header is shifting up out of the view by being pushed up by the next header view. I'll look into the key-value observation, unless you have another idea.

Comment: @user3188440 `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` also will be called continuous. Sorry for my mistake. You can have a try.

Comment: It is called continuously, but the reference to the header view is only updated once (when the view loads and scrollViewDidScroll is called first)...it doesn't track the change in visibleCells as the table scrolls.